# Production app crash report <compiler-generated>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm unable to recreate a crash happening for some of the app users from the app store and I can't figure it out.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010008d180
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [3253]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   FGS                             0x000000010008d180 LoginViewController.setupUI() + 896 (<compiler-generated>:94)
1   FGS                             0x000000010008cde4 @objc LoginViewController.viewDidLoad() + 96 (LoginViewController.swift:87)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0c64364 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 104 (UIViewController.m:2252)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0c68f98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 952 (UIViewController.m:3351)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0bd7c88 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 172 (UINavigationController.m:6332)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0bd7f9c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 180 (UINavigationController.m:6367)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0bd8db4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1104 (UINavigationController.m:6579)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0bda0f8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 168 (UINavigationController.m:6853)
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0bbd4e0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 228 (UILayoutContainerView.m:86)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1747abc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2156 (UIView.m:16956)
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019cf1faf0 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 68 (NSObject.mm:2182)
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a3ce60f4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 292 (CALayer.mm:9582)
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a3ce63fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 484 (CALayer.mm:9459)
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a3cf9964 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140 (CALayer.mm:2434)
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a3c3ec1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 308 (CAContextInternal.mm:1991)
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a3c69bd8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a12b7788 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 84 (UIApplication.m:10823)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d18507c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1774)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d184800 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d17f800 __CFRunLoopRun + 1088 (CFRunLoop.c:2884)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d17f098 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
21  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a72e9534 GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2246)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a129f7ac UIApplicationMain + 1940 (UIApplication.m:4753)
23  FGS                             0x000000010000da5c main + 68 (PolicyTableViewCell.swift:31)
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cffef30 start + 4
```

It says it crashes in `LoginViewController` `setupUI`, this is the code in that function:

```
private func setupUI() {
        let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
        var greetingMessage: String = ""

        switch hour {
        case 5..<12:
            greetingMessage = "Good morning"
        case 12..<18:
            greetingMessage = "Good afternoon"
        case 18..<24:
            greetingMessage = "Good evening"
        case 24..<5:
            greetingMessage = "Good night"
        default:
            break
        }

        //Using keychain to store user name is case of app deletion, so if reinstalled, will remember him and greet him again.
        if let fgsUser = keychain.get(Constants.kFgsUser) { 
            goodMorningLabel.text =
            """
            \(greetingMessage)
            \(fgsUser)
            """
        }
        else {
            goodMorningLabel.text = greetingMessage
        }
    }
```

for the keychain part I'm using `KeychainSwift` version 17.0

Comment: case 24..<5 this case is not working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the last case.

you need to replace 24 by 0.

```
private func setupUI() {
    let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
    var greetingMessage: String = ""

    switch hour {
    case 5..<12:
        greetingMessage = "Good morning"
    case 12..<18:
        greetingMessage = "Good afternoon"
    case 18..<24:
        greetingMessage = "Good evening"
    case 0..<5:
        greetingMessage = "Good night"
    default:
        break
    }

    //Using keychain to store user name is case of app deletion, so if reinstalled, will remember him and greet him again.
    if let fgsUser = keychain.get(Constants.kFgsUser) { 
        goodMorningLabel.text =
        """
        \(greetingMessage)
        \(fgsUser)
        """
    }
    else {
        goodMorningLabel.text = greetingMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that, I work during the days and never tried running the app during night time. how come the crash log don't show this error though? `Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound`